# Search an element in a subdocument using BSonDocument.GetElement

Tags: c#, mongodb

If i have a BSonDocument rappresenting something like this

```
{
   "name" : "hello"
   "subdoc": {
                "name": "bye"
             }
}
```

I can easily get "hello" using BSonDocument item.GetElement("name"), but how can i get "bye"?

Comment: you can find answer here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/89906 but first i think you should go through this tutorial http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I find it easiest to work with MongoDB and C#. I create a easily serialize-able class and use the LINQ features of the Mongo Driver. Hope this helps.

```
var databaseClient = new MongoClient(DatabaseConnectionString);
var server = databaseClient.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("YourDatabase");
var collection = database.GetCollection<YourObject>("YourObjects");

var subdoc = collection.AsQueryable().First(o => o.name == "hello").subdoc;
var subdocName = subdoc.name;

public class YourObject
{
    public string name;
    public OtherObject subdoc;
}

public class OtherObject
{
    public string name;
}
```